# jQuery change child text

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery function that changes a text inside a  element using a jquery "text" function. Inside this td element is child "a" tag like this.

`<td class="v3"><a href="somelink">text to change</a>`

The text to change is identified by the td class. When I change the text I lose the link. Question is how do I change the text using the parent element without touching the child (a href)?

Thanx

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you have:

```
<td class="v3">
     <a href="somelink">text to change</a>
</td>
```

Then in your function you should have something like this:

```
$("td.v3").children("a").text("new text");
```

However, this will select all links that are direct children of `td`s with class `.v3`. Adding a `.first()` after children should help:

```
$("td.v3").children("a").first().text("new text");
```

Comment: children works faster than $("td.v3 a") because the last mentioned selection is considered a candidate to go into sizzle - http://www.myinkblog.com/2009/09/11/sizzle-a-look-at-jquerys-new-css-selector-engine/ - which will take a few extra ms to run ;)

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the text in a `span` element, and change the text in the span.

```
<div id="foo">
    <span>bar</span>
    <a href="#">link</a>
</div>

...

$('#foo span').text('new text');
```

Edit:

Or use `$('td.v3 a').text("new text")` to change the text in the anchor, if that's what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

You would simply change another element's text.

```
<td>
   <a href="#">Link</a>
   <span>SomeText</span>
</td>
```

Then invoke like so:

```
$('td').find('span').text('myNewText');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change text in a select menu, you can do this by giving an option an id or class.

```
     $('selector').children('option[id=option_id]').text('new text');
```

Answer (score 0):

***Working Code !!***

using **child-selector** `>` with **pseudo-class** `:first-child`

```js
const changeIt = () => {
  $('div.v3 > a:first-child').text('New Text');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="v3">
  <a href="somelink">text to change</a>
</div>

<button onclick="changeIt()">
  Click
</button>
```