# How can i change the text inside a link with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink

I have the following link HTML:

```
  <a href="#" onclick="run(1); return false;" class="link" title="Remove item">[x]</a>
```

and i want to use jquery to change this to be

```
  <a href="#" onclick="run(1); return false;" class="link" title="Remove item">[x] Remove Item</a>
```

I want to keep the link and all of the attributes but change the text inside the link

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery change child text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415292/jquery-change-child-text)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the text in the link with the text() function and set it back with the text(String) function like this:

```
 $(".link").text($(".link").text() + " Remove Item");
```

And you can give your link a unique id if you wish to target just a single link rather than all elements with .link class.

Comment: Note that this will add the text of the first `.link` element to all others.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.link').text($('.link').text() + 'Remove Item');
```

OR

```
$('.link').each(function(){
    $(this).text($(this).text() + 'Remove item');
});
```

OR

```
$('.link').each(function(){
    $(this).text($(this).text() + $(this).attr('title'));
});
```

Comment: Better to use ID if need to change only one element.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var $link = $('a[title="Remove item"]');
$link.text($link.text()+ ' ' + $link.attr('title'));
```

---

**MORE:** The following is more obvious, but far less universal:

```
$('a[title="Remove item"]').text('[x] Remove item');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.link').each(function () {
    $(this).text($(this).text() + ' ' + $(this).attr('title'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use that:

```
jQuery(document).ready(
    function($)
    {
        if($('.link').text() == '[x]')
        {
           $('.link').text('[x] Remove');
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$("a.link").append('Remove item')
```