# Changing child buttons with parent button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to learn how to alter objects by referencing only the parent object. In this case I need three buttons; one that is the parent of the other two. When I click on the parent button, the text on both children should change. Trying this in jsFiddle, I have:

```
<body>

<button class="parent" id="btn1">Parent button
  <button class="child" id="childbtn1">child 1</button>
  <button class="child" id="childbtn2">child 2</button>
</button>

</body>
```

with the js:

```
document.getElementByClassName("parent").addEventListener('click',  
function() {
    $("btn1.child").innerHTML="new text";
});
```

I've looked at [similar posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415292/jquery-change-child-text), but for me this requirement of having to use buttons that are related is throwing me off. If the button elements are set up correctly (which I don't know if they are), should I be getting elements by id or by class to change the children? Thanks.

Comment: Please move your code into a snippet.

Comment: first you have a syntaxt error, it's `getElementsByClassName`, second it will return a collection, not the element, so you need to specify the index and your markup is pretty wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't put buttons inside of buttons.  If you open up inspect mode, you'll notice that children popped out of the parent button.  So if you were to change them to divs it would work fine.  Additionally, I converted your code to jQuery because you tagged the question as jQuery.

```js
$(".parent").click(function () {
  $(this).find(".child").html("new text");
});
```

```css
div {
  padding:30px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent" id="btn1">Parent button
  <div class="child" id="childbtn1">child 1</div>
  <div class="child" id="childbtn2">child 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. The way the prompt I have is worded, it sounds like buttons were supposed to be inside a parent button but that clears things up considering that isn't possible. Much appreciated.